# looping over grouped dataframe with multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I got a csv file that looks like the below table. For each folder, I wish to return the Image with the highest probability of being a 'Dog'. Each folder can only return one image. If Dog is not present, make 'Cat' with the highest probability the primary image. If there's no Cat, make Bird with the highest probability the primary image and so on.

CSV:

```
FolderName     ImageName    Predictions    Probabilities
   ABC           MyPet           Dog            0.98
   ABC           HisPet          Cat            0.90
   DEF           HerPet          Bird           0.83
   ABC           NotPet          Dog            0.23
   DEF           asdf            Dog            0.78
   DEF           M123            Cat            0.19
   GHI           M123s           Cat            0.89
   GHI           M13             Cat            0.19
```

I was only able to return the img with the highest probability, How can I Prioritize the Prediction column first then the Probabilities column?

```
df.loc[df.groupby('FolderName')['Probabilities'].idxmax()]
```

The code returns

```
FolderName     ImageName    Predictions    Probabilities
   ABC           MyPet           Dog            0.98
   DEF           asdf            Bird           0.83
   GHI           M123s           Cat            0.89
```

Desired result:

```
FolderName     ImageName    Predictions    Probabilities
   ABC           MyPet           Dog            0.98
   DEF           asdf            Dog            0.78
   GHI           M123s           Cat            0.89
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by converting "Predictions" to an ordered Categorical column, then calling `sort_values` and `drop_duplicates`.

```
df['Predictions'] = pd.Categorical(
    df['Predictions'], categories=['Dog', 'Cat', 'Bird'], ordered=True)

(df.sort_values(['Predictions', 'Probabilities'], ascending=[True, False])
   .drop_duplicates('FolderName'))

  FolderName ImageName Predictions  Probabilities
0        ABC     MyPet         Dog           0.98
4        DEF      asdf         Dog           0.78
6        GHI     M123s         Cat           0.89
```

Comment: @Mike I can categorically confirm that will not happen if you use this code. Please check your data, or edit your post with the offending row so I can debug. As you can see, this works for your input. Please check again.

Comment: @cs95 thank you :-) I recently close one newer question base on that tag , and feel like most of the answers under that question only cover primary key duplication removal ..